# How do I check if a key-value pair is present in a dictionary? If the value of one key is a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

```
a = {'a': 1, 'b': [{'a1': 1,'b2': 2}], 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 5}

b = {'c': 3, 'b': [{'a1': 1,'b2': 2}]}
```

Check for the presence of b in a, and the output is a `bool` value

Tried solutions like this:

```
    for values in b.items():
        if values in a.items():
            continue
        else:
            return False
    return True
```

```
len(set(b.items()) & set(a.items())) == len(b)
```

The problem is with a value-pair of a key-value whose value-pair is a dictionary. I am looking for a solution to this problem.

Comment: You want to see if two keys match? Or if one dictionary's (key, value) pairs are a subset of another?

Comment: Hi, I want to see if the pairs (key, value) match

Comment: Your question and code seem to suggest the opposite...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe this works for you?

```py
a = {'a': 1, 'b': [{'a1': 1,'b2': 2}], 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 5}
b = {'c': 3, 'b': [{'a1': 1,'b2': 2}]}
c = {'a1': 1,'b2': 3}

def issubset(a,b):
    for keyb,valueb in b.items():
        if keyb in a and a[keyb] == valueb: continue
        return False
    return True

print( issubset(a,b) )
print( issubset(a,c) )
print( issubset(a,{'a':'2'}) )
```

output:

```
True
False
False
```

it works for your example. However, as you see in the 2nd line, it doesn't do recursive checking, which might be what you want.